# Running multiple instances of selenium webdriver asynchronously (firefox)

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

How can I make my webdriver request multiple pages (or open multiple browsers) at the same time, concurrently?

All solutions I found on the internet waits until the previous session has finished loading and only then open a new instance of the browser.

I have tried selenium-webdriver, webdriverjs and wdjs, and none of them seem to be able to do multiple http requests for different pages asynchronously. Even solutions like this https://github.com/OniOni/wd-parallel-async wont work. They all open one at time.

Am I missing something?

PS: I don't want to run multiple browsers concurrently! I want to run multiple instances of the same browser.

Comment: I think I misunderstood a little the webdrivers.

Yes, they all seem to open one at time, but once they are open I can manage them independently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
WebDriver driver1 = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriver driver2 = new FirefoxDriver();
WebDriver driver3 = new FirefoxDriver();
driver1.get("page1");
driver2.get("page2");
driver3.get("page3");
```

If you need it truly asynchronous, then you will need to get into Java threading ... which would make this into a longer discussion and off-topic for SO.

Comment: Do you know if cookies will be shared between the instances? I need them to be isolated and have its own cookie jar.

Comment: Each `WebDriver driverX = new FirefoxDriver();` will create a new instance of Firefox with it's own separate profile ... and separate Cookie store.

Comment: Ok, I just tested that, you are right ;) Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: Do Chrome and IE drivers support similar isolated instances?

Comment: I assume it means that you will get a separate session per browser instance, correct?

Answer (score 1):

Utilize threading.  I see you have node.js tagged...I am not as familiar with that, but below is a c# example that works...similar theory should apply.
c#

```
    Parallel.Invoke(
        ()=> { 1st test execution call },
        ()=> { 2nd test execution call },
        ()=> { 3rd test execution call }
    );
```

Although be careful as the webdriver can sometimes get confused and overlap windows.  I have found that doing more than 5 at a time on a single machine leads to miscellaneous problems.  If you use the `Parallel.Invoke` in c# you can throttle this to only allow a certain number at a time...although Grid is the best way to do that as you setup your limits in configuration and then it load balances for you.